# Validating Dimension text input javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

How to validate a asp textbox with javascript.
I want to validate a users input which is something like 4-1/2 or 80-1/2 or 6/8 or 5.
There are the types of patterns there only be allowed and always contains one number.
I want to show an alert when the input doesn't match.
I am a beginner with javascript.

My code I tried.

```
function valid_Dimentions(fieldObj) {
 // regular expression
 var rgexp = new RegExp(""/^[0-9/-]{1,4}$/"");
 var input = fieldObj.value;
     if (input.match(rgexp))
         alert("The width field format is incorrect!");                    
}
```

I used this for money and works and used it to build my non working code.

```
function valid_number(fieldObj) {
 if (fieldObj.value != '' && isNaN(fieldObj.value)) {
    alert('You must enter a valid price like 0.00 and no $');
    fieldObj.select();
    fieldObj.focus();
    return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

...

```
<asp:TextBox id="TWidth" type="text" runat="server" placeholder="4-1/2" onchange="valid_Dimentions_Width(this);"  list="PartType" runat="server" required="required" Width="210px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

Comment: use the input pattern attrib, then feed that to js instead of making validation JS-only.

Comment: have you sorted this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Avoid using `alert`. Instead, just fill some element with the error message.
- Avoid validating on client only, validate that on your server side as well.
- Your `if` is displaying the error when the match is true. It should negate it.
- Your regex is wrong, it's just checking if it's a 1 to 4 digit number.
- You can declare a regex by enclosing between `/`'s

Here's the regex i came with:

```
^([0-9]+|[0-9]+-[0-9]+\/[0-9]+|[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)$
```

It checks if your number is one of the following:

- Pure number: `[0-9]+`
- Number folowed by `-` followed by number/number: `[0-9]+-[0-9]+\/[0-9]+`
- Number/Number: `[0-9]+\/[0-9]+`

See that i have to scape `/` with `\` so the regex definition is not messed up.

Here's the final code:

```
function valid_Dimensions_Width(fieldObj) {
    var error = ""
    var rgexp = /^([0-9]+|[0-9]+-[0-9]+\/[0-9]+|[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)$/;
    var input = fieldObj.value;
    if (!input.match(rgexp)) error = "The width field format is incorrect!";
    document.getElementById("TWidthError").innerHTML = error;
}
```

And working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3f5skp8/

I replaced `onChange` for `onKeyUp` so it shows the feedback instantly.